# Visual Studio 2008 Hide the Undo Close window

Tags: visual-studio-2008, powercommands

All of a sudden, my Visual Studio 2008 Pro install is doing something very annoying (I know, hard to believe, right?)

For any existing project I load, the Undo Close window opens as a floating window. Even if I close the window and save the SLN, it continues to pop up.

Anyone know how I can stop it from opening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Workaround from MSDN by changing the Windows Registry

> http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=15

Open **Regedit** and go to the **`{eccc9e97-fd3b-4c15-af76-ef71a71d8b17}`** folder (depends on your OS, see below) and remove the **`Visibility`** subfolder. Then just **restart Visual Studio** and you are done.

**Windows 7 32-bit:** `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ToolWindows\{eccc9e97-fd3b-4c15-af76-ef71a71d8b17}`

**Windows 7 64-bit:** `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ToolWindows\{eccc9e97-fd3b-4c15-af76-ef71a71d8b17}`

Comment: the reg entry modification fixed it. cant believe i didnt find this before. thanks